# remove plugun instance

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using [jquery.timepickr.js](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/). I want to be able to change the parameters, something like:

```
$('aField').timepickr( some default parameters);
```

User makes some choices:

```
$('aField').remove(timepickr);
$('aField').timepickr(some_other_parameters_reflecting_user_choices);
```

How can I destroy/unlink/remove/disassociate an instance of timepickr?

I have also tried `$('aField').timepickr('destroy');`

Answer (score 3):

Their destroy function is not correctly cleaning up, as a work-around, try this:

```
$('aField').timepickr('destroy').next(".ui-timepickr").remove(); //Blow it away
$('aField').timepicker(); //Bring it back, new options
```

Only change is we're cleaning up the elements it creates after destroying the widget itself.